# How to get more fields from another object with an IN statement

Tags: soql

I use the following query to get the data, but i also want to receive more fields from the "soco__Volunteer_Assignment__c" object.

`SELECT+FIELDS(ALL),Account.Name,Account.Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Id+IN+(SELECT+soco__Contact__c+FROM+soco__Volunteer_Assignment__c+WHERE+soco__Status__c='Active'+LIMIT+2+OFFSET+0`

How do I receive more fields from this object?

`SELECT+FIELDS(ALL),Account.Name,Account.Id+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Id+IN+(SELECT+soco__Contact__c,soco__End_Date__c+FROM+soco__Volunteer_Assignment__c+WHERE+soco__Status__c='Active'+LIMIT+2+OFFSET+0`

placing the fieldname "soco__End_Date__c" in the second select query will receive the folowing error message:

```
[
    {
        "message": "\nWHERE Id IN (SELECT soco__Contact__c,soco__End_Date__c FROM soco__Volunteer_Assignment__c\n                                   ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:321\nunexpected token: ,",
        "errorCode": "MALFORMED_QUERY"
    }
]
```

Comment: The error message says the field `Id` only receives the ID values, not an object `soco__Volunteer_Assignment__c`.

Comment: Please only ever add the `[community]` badge if you are asking a question related to the `Salesforce Community Cloud` feature (also called `Experience Cloud`).

Answer (score 1):

It's a different type of join to retrieve child objects than it is to filter on them. There used to be really good documentation on join syntax, but it seems to have disappeared.

I believe what you already have is a `Left Inner Join`, and what you need to add is a `Left Outer Join`. In this terminology, `Left` indicates a child table, and `Right` indicates a parent table. Further, `Inner` indicates joining via `WHERE` filtering, whereas `Outer` indicates pulling in records/fields via `SELECT` clause.

Anyway, what you need should look like:

```
SELECT FIELDS(ALL), Parent.Field, (SELECT Field__c FROM Children__r)
FROM Contact WHERE Id IN (SELECT Contact_Lookup__c FROM Child__c)
```

Note the names in the `FROM` clause are different in the two joins. When pulling child records into your `SELECT` clause, you need to use the `Child Relationship Name`, whereas you use the `Qualified API Name` when joining via your `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Thanks, by using this method I receive the following message

```SELECT+FIELDS(ALL),Account.Name,(SELECT+soco__End_Date__c+FROM+soco__Volunteer_Assignment__r)+FROM+Contact+WHERE+Id+IN+(SELECT+soco__Contact__c+FROM+soco__Volunteer_Assignment__c)```

Comment: ```
[
    {
        "message": "\n(SELECT soco__End_Date__c FROM soco__Volunteer_Assignment__r) FROM\n                               ^\nERROR at Row:1:Column:64\nDidn't understand relationship 'soco__Volunteer_Assignment__r' in FROM part of query call. If you are attempting to use a custom relationship, be sure to append the '__r' after the custom relationship name. Please reference your WSDL or the describe call for the appropriate names.",
        "errorCode": "INVALID_TYPE"
    }
]
```

Comment: **[How do I find the child relationship name?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/q/140926/2995)**